# Better way to show Hermitian 2x2 matrix is positive definie

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a more elegant way to show that a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ is positive definite when $Tr(A)=1$ and $Tr(A^2) \leq 1$ and $A = A^\dagger$.

I find the proof below clumsy and long, and it doesn't provide much insight to larger matrices where this isn't true.

$$
A =\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\  \overline{c} &b\end{pmatrix} \\
Tr(A)=a + b = 1 \\
Tr(A^2)=a^2 + b^2 + 2\bar{c}c  = a^2 + (1-a)^2 + 2\bar{c}c \leq 1 \\
\bar{c}c \leq a - a^2 \\
x^*Ax = a\bar{x}x + b\bar{y}y + \bar{x}cy + x\bar{c}\bar{y} = a\bar{x}x + b\bar{y}y + 2 Re(\bar{x}cy) \\
Re(\bar{x}cy) \leq (\bar{c}c\bar{x}x\bar{y}y)^{1/2} \leq (a(1-a)\bar{x}x\bar{y}y)^{1/2} \\
a\bar{x}x + b\bar{y}y = a\bar{x}x + (1-a)\bar{y}y \geq 2 (a(1-a)\bar{x}x\bar{y}y)^{1/2} \\
u + v \geq 2(uv)^{1/2} \\
u^2 + v^2 + 2uv \geq 4 uv \\
u^2 + v^2 \geq 2 uv \\
a\bar{x}x + b\bar{y}y \geq |\bar{x}cy + x\bar{c}\bar{y}| \\
\therefore x^*Ax \geq 0
$$

Comment: You can use Sylvester's criterion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: Positive <b>semi</b>definite. For example,$$A = \operatorname{diag}(1,0) = A^\dagger$$ fulfills all of your conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is more elegant, but since the matrix is Hermitian we need only look at eigenvalues to determine definiteness. Also, since it is Hermitian, the eigenvalues are real.

The trace of a matrix is the sum of the diagonals, hence the sum of the eigenvalues.

This gives $\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = 1$, $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2 \le 1$, or letting $\lambda_2 = 1-\lambda_1$, we get 
$(\lambda_1-1)\lambda_1 \le 0$, which is equivalent to $\lambda_1 \in [0,1]$. Similarly we get $\lambda_2 \in [0,1]$. Since they are both non-negative, we see that the matrix is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Seems like a decent answer and helps me show for $n \geq 2$ this doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent characterization of hermitian matrices is that the eigenvalues be positive. Citation: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations)

Further, the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and the trace is the sum of eigenvalues. So, if both your trace and determinant is non-negative for a $2\times 2$ matrix, you have a positive semidefinite matrix.

---

Now, you have shown (Line 4), $$a-a^2\geq c\bar{c}$$
Working from there:
\begin{align}
det(A)&=ab-c\bar{c}\\
&=a(1-a)-c\bar{c}\\
&=a-a^2-c\bar{c}\geq 0 \\
\end{align}
Thus, you have positive trace and non-negative determinant.

Comment: I think you have the order for determinant and trace mixed up in regards to being product and sum of eigenvalues.

Comment: @Roland, Nice catch. Thanks!